# Using guid id in Entity Framework Web Api and DbContext Find not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a class that has Guid id.

```
public class Product { 
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
}
```

and I am using this context in my web api application.

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
        readonly ProductContext database = new ProductContext();

        public IHttpActionResult Get(string id){
              database.find(id); // does not find.
        }
}
```

if I change action parameter as guid it finds.

```
        public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid id){
              database.find(id); // finds.
        }
```

But if a user sends invalid id parameter, applicaiton throws exception.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method
>   'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult Get(System.Guid)

Should I make all of `id` properties as string? Which way is best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use a `Guid?`

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid? id)
{
    if (id.HasValue)
    {
        database.find(id.Value); // finds.
    }
    else
    {
        // invalid ID
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: Does nullable Guid instance binds by defalut model binder?

Comment: Nullable types should be handled correctly. If you do have issues, I'd be interested to see how your routing is configured.

Answer (score 0):

cast string to Guid.

```
 public class ProductController : ApiController
    {
            readonly ProductContext database = new ProductContext();

            public IHttpActionResult Get(string id){

                  database.find(new Guid(id)); 
            }
    }
```